# What type of character encoding is this, and what's the best datatype to use in MySql to store it?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I'm probably asking all the wrong questions, but here goes. I'm testing out encryption using the php-encryption software here https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/

I've created my encrypted data, and am storing it as the data type of TEXT in the database, What's the longest, and most forgiving table data type to use for the text below?

```
”6f0Sv—y:6^È1Öˆ]a¢T”„eŠ…2¦ïaö´/jqWžõkg´Ëô%»ÉHƒ«x©3uK³$7¡héMêž8øHÓ›â%1ÔÙqP:9qƒGnz¬,Ùf
°³”4Ý[Éî
ê,R+{Ÿ¢ñöaGuüÎO–Èý©P¹—œ6 f
```

For now I'm base64encoding it and testing, but if there is a better way, I'd love to hear it. The characters, plus any I may have missed here (the diamond with a triangle) mess up the database, and often don't save.

Comment: Base 64 encoding sounds OK and would be useful in case you need to send this data somewhere in a response to a web service call.

Comment: i vote for BLOB in this case

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the max size of the data you are storing, as per your example the base64 encoding sound ok in a **varchar** field.

But consider that Base64 will increase the size of the message to 4 *n* /3, being *n* the length of your message.

If you want to avoid making conversions you can also consider **blob** [datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html).

Answer (score 0):

> What type of character encoding is this?

**It's not encoded, it's raw binary.**

> what's the best datatype to use in MySql to store it?

You can store it in a `BLOB` field (assuming you use prepared statements), or you can base64-encode it then store it, as Alariva suggested.

---

Just a head's up, v2.0.0 [might encode the ciphertext by default](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/issues/76#issuecomment-124274429).